# All LaTeX commands list

Tags: tex-core

I'm writing a LaTeX commands highlighter in C#, for this I need all or most of the LaTeX commands. 
I've searched the web and found many lists of commands but all of them are with comments and explanations that I don't need. Before I'll spend entire week deleting the unnecessary comments leaving only the commands. 
I would like to ask you, is there somewhere a simple text list of the commands, like this:

```
...
\backslash
\bar
\baselineskip
\baselinestretch
...
```

Comment: There is no such list. Most people do highlighting using TeX's own rules: a command is ``\`` followed by one non-letter or one or more letters. (That's assuming you are not also wanting internal commands, which in traditional TeX may also contain `@` as a 'letter'.)

Comment: As that is useful to you, I'll post as a slightly expanded 'proper' answer.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Regex is for processing text, not structured languages. There are tons of good parser-combinator libraries for .NET, the best of which, in my opinion, is FParsec (though that requires F#). Using a parser means your code is readable, reusable, maintainable, and improvable. A parser allows you to capture the semnatic content. Regex allows you to capture characters.

Comment: Not familiar with F# at all. Just heard that it exists.

Comment: To underline @Greg's point, [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/773/1410) is my earlier try at some TeX rexps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is possible to list all TeX primitives or all LaTeX kernel commands, there is no list of all possible LaTeX commands as new ones can be added by packages. As such, most people use an approach of searching for the same pattern as TeX does: `\` followed by either one non-letter or one or more letters: this is the pattern for 'document commands'.

(It is possible for commands not to start with `\`, but this is used for internal coding and not in documents. Similarly, internal commands often use one or more extra 'letters': `@` is traditional while LaTeX3 uses `_` and `:`. However, for the purposes of highlighting in a document these cases can be ignored.)

Comment: How is this particular RegExp looks like? Having difficulty to create such myself :(

Comment: `\\([^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: @David Carlisle Thought about it but it seems that I also catch illegal commands such as chapter\ instead of \chapter

Comment: No it means literal ``\`` followed by the choice group of a single non letter `[^a-zA-Z]` or 0-more letters `[a-zA-Z]+` so would not match ``chapter\``

Comment: + is 1 or more (which is what you want) not 0 or more as I mis-wrote above